# Not able to get the requested URL in django new version

Tags: python, django, web, django-3.2

When the default url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` is given then the app is able to get the default page but when I tried to connect with the pages using
 `http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/`
I'm getting this error as a traceback

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/
Using the URLconf defined in crm.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, customer/, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Here is my code crm/urls.py--->

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),

]
```

now accounts/urls.py--->

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home,name="ShopHome"),
    path('products/', views.products,name="ProductsHome"),
    path('customer/', views.customer,name="customerHome"),
]
```

Now accounts/view.py--->

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse



def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('home')

def products(request):
    return HttpResponse('products')

def customer(request):
    return HttpResponse('customer')
```

and this is myinstalled apps in setting-->

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
]
```

Please help me out guys I'm struck here for 2 days

Comment: How about http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/customer/

Comment: Still Not working

Comment: Is `accounts` an item in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: yes it's.```ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
]```

Answer (score 0):

You need to point to the `urls` of the `accounts` app *without* a leading `accounts/`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #    ↓↓ empty string
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

otherwise you can access the customer view with:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/customer/
```

but that is likely *not* what you want.

Comment: Sorry I tried in both ways still getting the same error

Comment: @Selva: you can not combine both, you should pick *one* of the two.

Comment: Yeah That's what I did. I meant I tried each one of them seperatly

Comment: @Selva: can you please post the *full* traceback? Please *edit* your question.

Comment: You mean the entire code? or some other thing. Sorry not able to get you

Comment: @Selva: what exactly does it show when you accessing the URL? When you work with `DEBUG = True`, it should print data to diagnoze the problem.

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer
Using the URLconf defined in crm.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, customer, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.@Willem Van Onsem

Comment: @Selva: what if you use a *trailing* slash:  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/`

Comment: Already did still the same error? Would you like to connect with me if possible?

Comment: @Selva: can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67657695/edit) the question and include the traceback (in a code environment), suc that no post-processing is done on the data through HTML rendering.

Comment: Yeah done now .Kindly check it once please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232761/discussion-between-selva-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hi, i'm having similar issue i upgraded from django 1.9 to 3.2 with alot and alot of updates now it comes to this point that application is successfully running the server, but i get the Page not found on whatever url i put, seems like there's a disconnect between url configurations, any help is appericated